Trying to understand C++ multiple print functions
I've been learning C++ for the past months but I keep on getting stuck on the printing functions. I currently know of two main ways of printing - printf() and cout <<. There is also OutputDebugString() that I used for a project some time ago, but it doesn't seem to be used very often.
I've noticed that printf() seems to be used for strings. But I wanted to see if anyone could explain why both seem to exist as part of C++. Many tutorials seem to point towards cout <<, but I've also seen the other option be used for some code challenges.

printf is C function and is difficult to use in a type-safe manner. std::cout is C++ way to print things type-safely. OutputDebugString is Windows only macro.

printf is not a part of C++, it's a part of C and the function is in the section C-style file input/output

Ok thanks that helps. Also how did someone find that post? I tried to look initially but I only found basic tutorials on how to use both options. I assume thats why I got the downvote.

Since C++23 there is nice to use std::print, which is based on fmt library. It is safe, user friendly and fastest. printf is C API which is very bug prone (especially when beginner do not uses proper compilation flags).

The printf has a limited set of format-specifiers.

Have you tried putting the square peg in the round hole? Maybe that will work

The printf and std::count may not share the same buffering schemes, so don't mix them.

Side note: Once you notice that std::cout is an instance of std::basic_ostream there are also: std::cout.put, std::cout.write, print( cout, ) and a few others depending on your needs.

@MontainProduction "Also how did someone find that post?" - if you are referring to the duplicate I was familiar with it also because I wrote an answer there with info about the C++23 std::print mentioned above.

Nothing wrong with this question other than it having been asked before. May it have a long and happy life as a signpost.

Makes sense. Was just a bit suprised that someone thought it was worth a downvote. Still getting used to asking and answering questions and what makes something a downvote vs not.

@MontainProduction I didn't downvote. But maybe somebody thought you haven't researched enough before posting the question (as you can see in [ask]).

Wasent blaming anyone. More just saying it out loud. Wanted to understand a bit more why it might of happened.

One down-or-up vote generally isn't worth worrying about. I agree with wolstad's assumption of a "lack  of research" vote, but you'll find there's somebody who'll up-or-down vote anything. In this case it could just have been someone grumpy from lack of coffee. Multiple votes is where you have to start paying attention.

That said, in the early going, you need to be really careful about your question-asking as the server doesn't seem to care about how much reputation you have, but cares a lot about the scoring of the questions. If the average score of all your questions (including the deleted ones) is zero or less after somewhere between five or ten questions, the server stops accepting new questions, capping you at about 1 question every six months. You kind of have to game the system in the beginning. Pick your next question carefully and you'll be fine.

I didnt know that stackoverflow would check the average score and essentially shadow ban a user. Ya Ill do my best with my next question a bit better.

Ja. Documentation is weak on this. Nobody seems to know until they get the "Not accepting questions from this account" message. Then the first thing they do is delete all of their downvoted questions and find that doesn't help. Maybe then they arrive at meta.stackoverflow.com and get helped out, but more likely they mumble something like " this." and we never see them again.
